# Left-hand side of assignment expression cannot be a constant or a read-only property

Tags: express, angular, mongoose, angular2-universal, typescript2.0

When I use this line on my Express server, it works well in TypeScript 1.x

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

( The usage of `mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;` is from [the mongoose document](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) )

After updating to TypeScript 2.x, it shows this error in the terminal, and won't let me start the server.

> Left-hand side of assignment expression cannot be a constant or a
>   read-only property.

How can I solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is because in `es6` all *module's* variables are considered **constants**.

> https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6751#issuecomment-177114001

In `TypeScript 2.0` the bug (of not reporting this error) was fixed.

Since `mongoose` is still using the `commonjs` - `var mongoose = require("mongoose")` - not the `es6` import syntax (which is used in the typings), you can suppress the error by assuming the module is of type `any`.

**WORKAROUND:**

```js
(mongoose as any).Promise = global.Promise;
```

Comment: thank you! just added another similar way: `(<any>mongoose).Promise = global.Promise;`

Answer (score 2):

There is also a way to maintain type-checking and intellisense with this technique.

```js
import * as mongoose from "mongoose"; // same as const mongoose = require("mongoose");
type mongooseType = typeof mongoose;
(mongoose as mongooseType).Promise = global.Promise;
// OR
(<mongooseType>mongoose).Promise = global.Promise;
```

This can be a helpful way to override only certain functions within a module with mock functions without needing a mock framework like `jest.mock()`.